# Are 401k and IRAs protected the same way during bankruptcy?

Tags: 401k, ira, bankruptcy

I've heard that IRAs offer a better protection during bankruptcy but i can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.entrepreneur.com/money/personalfinance/personalfinancecolumnistdebraneiman/article79452.html), it seems like 401(k)s have unlimited protection, while IRA's have up to $1m in protection.

It seems like it's kind of complicated. If you are trying to protect more than $1,000,000 in retirement assets during a personal bankrupcy, you can probably afford to have a good lawyer give you advice.

Comment: I'd also question why you are filing bankruptcy if you have $1M in liquid assets, unless you are Mike Tyson.

Comment: @JohnFx: most types of retirement assets can't be taken out early without penalty, so they're not liquid

Comment: They are liquid, it just doesn't make a lot of financial sense to draw on them early except in emergencies. I'd consider an impending bankruptcy an emergency.