# Are IRAs and 401(k)s protected against lawsuits and garnishments?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, lawsuit-settlement

There's as similar question about [bankruptcy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5006/are-401k-and-iras-protected-the-same-way-during-bankruptcy), but these protections apply to lawsuits or garnishments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an article [Can an IRA be Taken in a Lawsuit](http://bestirarescue.com/ira-lawsuit.html) it would seem that the IRA offers less protection than the 401(k). This is consistent with other articles I've read.

You don't ask about divorce. In a divorce, the 401(k) is fair game and it's one of the times such accounts can be transferred to another individual with no tax consequence. This is through the process know as QDRO (Qualified domestic relations order) in which the 401(k) is split to give a portion to the spouse.